# Aligning text and chapter/section titles, not with the numbers

Tags: margins, titlesec, layout

I am writing a user manual (pdfLatex and MikTeX) for my company and would like to match a layout I've found on another manual :

- Chapter and sections number are on the left
- Chapter (section) titles are shifted on the right
- Text is aligned with the chapter and sections titles (not with the numbers)
- Images, tables and equations can take the whole place within margins.

I basically look for a solution for the whole document like this example :
[image]

I tried to use the titlesec package to edit the chapter and sections titles layout. That works but the text in these sections stay aligned with the numbers, not the title itself.

I also tried to change the margins of my document, but then the chapter number are also shifted (I would like them to stay on the left like in the picture). This method also shift the images and tables which I want to keep centered on the page.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would use paracol.  The full width can be accessed by turning off paracol (like  multicol).

Comment: How about setting the division (chapter/section) numbers into the margin and extending the header into the margin to cover these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching and testing, I've found a quite easy solution using `\leftskip`. This only shifts the "text margins" without affecting the figures, tables, lists and titles.

Combined with a tuning of titles layout with the `titlesec` package and adding margins to the lists with the `enumitem` package, it works perfectly :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\leftskip}{2cm}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{1.3cm}{}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1.2cm}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\section{title}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may require more tweaking.  It seems some things need to be done outside paracol (`\pagestyle`?).  Also, `\section` will be more difficult as it uses `\@startsection`.  I would redefine `\section` to be more like `\chapter`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\end{paracol}
                    %\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
                    
\def\@makechapterhead#1{\vspace*{20\p@}% adjustable
  \begin{paracol}{2}
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \huge\bfseries %\@chapapp\space 
      \thechapter\par\vfill
    \fi}
  \switchcolumn
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@% adjustable
  }}
\makeatother
\setcolumnwidth{3cm}% second column take rest of page

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
First column
\switchcolumn
Second column

\chapter{Title}

\lipsum[1]
\end{paracol}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but  unfortunately that's a bit "heavy", since I want my whole document like that, that would require to use the paracol environment between every figure/table.